# Inexplicable ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=3

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, popen

I am finalising moving my code from python2.7 to python3.5 and turned on `warnings` to check another module.
When using `os.popen()` I am getting the following error.

```
ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 encoding='UTF-8'>
```

The number in the above example "name=3" will change, depending on the code but it is always a integer.
This code snippet produces the error and yet no file has been opened, which is in complete conflict with the error message `unclosed file`.
My environment is Linux using python 3.5.2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import warnings
import os
warnings.simplefilter('default')
sink_list = os.popen('pacmd list-sinks | grep "name:" | cut --delimiter=: -f2').readlines()
print (sink_list)
sink = os.popen('pacmd list | grep "Default sink name" | cut --delimiter=: -f2').readline()
print(sink)
```

Results in the following:

```
test.py:6: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 encoding='UTF-8'>
  sink_list = os.popen('pacmd list-sinks | grep "name:" | cut --delimiter=: -f2').readlines()
[' <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>\n', ' <fs2-Equaliser>\n', ' <fs2-bs2b>\n']
test.py:8: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 encoding='UTF-8'>
  sink = os.popen('pacmd list | grep "Default sink name" | cut --delimiter=: -f2').readline()
 fs2-Equaliser
```

Does anyone know why this warning is issued, especially in this circumstance, where no file has been opened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer is a *file descriptor*, the integer number the OS uses to talk about file handles assigned to a process. `0`, `1` and `2` are `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, 3 and up are further file descriptors used.

You get the resource warning because you open the file handle, but never close it explicitly. You instead just call `.readlines()` or `.readline()` on the Python file object wrapper:

```
sink_list = os.popen('pacmd list-sinks | grep "name:" | cut --delimiter=: -f2').readlines()
```

This leaves the file object to be closed by the garbage collector, and you get the warning. You can use the open object as a context manager to have it closed for you:

```
 with os.popen('pacmd list-sinks | grep "name:" | cut --delimiter=: -f2') as list_sinks:
    sink_list = list_sinks.readlines()
```

Personally, I'd use the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to handle external processes, and use Python to do the line selection. This lets you avoid spinning up a separate `sh` process and generally has much nicer exception handling:

```
import subprocess

# read list of sinks
result = suprocess.run(['pacmd', 'list-sinks'], stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding='UTF-8')
sink_list = [l.split(':', 2) for l in result.stdout if 'name:' in l]

# read default sink
result = suprocess.run(['pacmd', 'list'], stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding='UTF-8')
default_sink = next((l.split(':', 2) for l in result.stdout if 'Default sink name' in l), None)
```