# Python Popen stdin.close + wait() generates ResourceWarning in unittest

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Python class that inherits from Popen:

```
class S(Popen):
    def exit(self):
        self.stdin.close()
        return self.wait()
```

This works fine, except that if I call the `exit()` method on my Python unit test (using the built-in 'unittest' framework), the following error comes up when running the test:

> /usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py:600: ResourceWarning: unclosed
>   file <_io.TextIOWrapper name=5 encoding='UTF-8'>   testMethod()

Here's the test code:

```
class TestS(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_exit(self):
        s = S()
        self.assertTrue(s.exit() == 0)
```

I know it's triggered by the `return self.wait()` line because there are no other files being opened and if it's replaced by `return 0` the warning goes away.

Is there something else that needs to be done for proper clean-up? Perhaps something equivalent to `pclose()` in C? Found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124745/inexplicable-resourcewarning-unclosed-file-io-textiowrapper-name-3) helpful but it doesn't really help solve this issue. The test passes, but I'd rather not suppress the warning, without understanding the cause.

Some things I already tried, with no success:

- Did a `with S() as s` block
- Same as above with `self.exit()` being called by a destructor (`def __exit__)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the warning might refer to the stdout/stderr of the subprocess, particularly if you were using subprocess.PIPE for either of them.

I had the same issue myself, and it went away after adding calls to to `proc.stdout.close()` and `proc.stderr.close()` after wait returns.